# No 'IIS 7 Deployment Handler' in Web Deploy Installer (MSI)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

I'm trying to install Web Deployment Tool 2.0 on my Windows Server 2008 R2.

The problem is that I can't see option 'IIS 7 Deployment Handler' in the feature customization screen during setup while I CAN see it if I install on the similar server.

I suspect my main server doesn't meet some requirements, but which ones?Or is the problem in other area?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, I found the solution. My main server didn't have Management Service installed. Once I have installed, it (IIS -> Add Role Service -> Management Tools -> Management Service), it started working as expected